For $n=14$, $\sigma_0(n) = \sigma_0(n+1)$ and $\sigma_1(n) = \sigma_1(n+1)$. Are there any other cases?
Let $\sigma_x(n)$ be the sum of the $x^\text{th}$ powers of the divisors of $n$. (So $\sigma_0(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$ and $\sigma_1(n)$ is the sum of those divisors.)
It's known that $\sigma_0(n) = \sigma_0(n+k)$ has infinitely many solutions for any positive integer $k$. (See, e.g., here.) In particular, there are infinite pairs of consecutive integers (the case $k=1$) with the same number of divisors.
According to OEIS A002961, it's an open problem whether $\sigma_1(n) = \sigma_1(n+1)$ has a finite number of solutions.
It's also known that $\sigma_2(n) = \sigma_2(n+1)$ has exactly one solution: $n=6$. (See here, for instance.)
The only solution I know where both $\sigma_0(n) = \sigma_0(n+1)$ and $\sigma_1(n) = \sigma_1(n+1)$ is $n=14$.
So I have two questions:

What is known about the problem $\sigma_1(n) = \sigma_1(n+1)$?
What about the problem $\sigma_0(n) = \sigma_0(n+1)$ and $\sigma_1(n) = \sigma_1(n+1)$ simultaneously?


I feel like the $\sigma_1$ problem is still open....

@GregMartin - Yes, I just discovered that and updated my question.

there are many,   I have 1831 examples  by downloading https://oeis.org/A002961/b002961.txt   and checking for equal divisor count.

yes, sure,   you can check
I have the first  1831 examples by downloading
https://oeis.org/A002961/b002961.txt
and comparing divisor counts for $n$ and $n+1.$ I use C++ with GMP,  as they let me take a self-paced course in C++ and even told me my grade, this being about 1994.
That list has the first 10135   examples  with matching sigma.
n     : 9984331805444 =  2^2 29 131 659 997021
n +1: 9984331805445 =  3^2 5 19 769 15185411
evidently both sigma are  18240716894400
the first example after 14 is
n: 1334 =  2 23 29   n +1: 1335 =  3 5 89
a: 8 b: 8 c: 2160 d: 2160
each 8 divisors and sigma 2160
let's see
$3\cdot24 \cdot30 = 2160$
$4\cdot6\cdot90 = 2160$
 k: 1 n: 14 =  2 7   n +1: 15 =  3 5    
 k: 4 n: 1334 =  2 23 29   n +1: 1335 =  3 5 89    
 k: 6 n: 1634 =  2 19 43   n +1: 1635 =  3 5 109    
 k: 7 n: 2685 =  3 5 179   n +1: 2686 =  2 17 79    
 k: 15 n: 33998 =  2 89 191   n +1: 33999 =  3 7 1619    
 k: 17 n: 42818 =  2 79 271   n +1: 42819 =  3 7 2039    
 k: 19 n: 64665 =  3^3 5 479   n +1: 64666 =  2 7 31 149    
 k: 23 n: 84134 =  2 23 31 59   n +1: 84135 =  3 5 71 79    
 k: 25 n: 109214 =  2 7 29 269   n +1: 109215 =  3^3 5 809    
 k: 28 n: 122073 =  3 7 5813   n +1: 122074 =  2 67 911    

